# Ubuntu GNOME 14.10 can't use multiple languages

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, 14.10

I recently updated to UBUNTU GNOME 14.10 GNOME version 3.14.1.

I tried adding more languages to the keyboard such as Hebrew, It let's me add it, but when I am changing the language it does show in the top right corner but the typing is still in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install *ibus-m17n* and add *Hebrew (kbd (m17n))*.

Comment: I installed ibus-m17n, what do you mean by "add Hebrew (kbd (m17n))."?

Comment: @Rosenpin: I mean the same way as when you added "Hebrew". (You may need to log out and log in again for the additional options to show up.)

Comment: @Rosenpin: You're welcome. :)